# Coordinate transformation second order partial derivative is zero using chain rule?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, differential-geometry, general-relativity, jacobian

The question uses Einstein notation: In a coordinate transformation $ x^{\mu} \rightarrow   x'^{ \mu '}$ is $$ \frac{\partial ^2 x'^{ \mu '}}{\partial x^{\sigma} \partial x^{\mu}} \frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x'^{\beta '}} =
 \frac{\partial }{\partial x'^{\beta '}} \left[ \frac{\partial x'^{ \mu '} } {\partial x^{ \sigma} } \right]= 
\frac{\partial }{\partial x^{\sigma}} \left[ \frac{\partial x'^{ \mu '} } {\partial x'^{ \beta '} } \right] = 0 $$

If not why? Isn't $x' ^{\mu '}(x^{\sigma},x'^{\beta '}) \in C^2$ ?

Weirdly using this 'identity' it was somewhat easier to transform the Christoffel symbols and it gave the correct result.

It does not however give correct results under a 2-d Cartesian to polar transformation.